# How to create on click event for buttons in swing?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

My task is to retrieve the value of a text field and display it in an alert box when clicking a button. How do I generate the on click event for a button in Java Swing?

Answer (score 64):

For that, you need to use [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html), for example:

```
JButton b = new JButton("push me");
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //your actions
    }
});
```

For generating click event programmatically, you can use [`doClick()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick%28%29) method of `JButton`: `b.doClick();`

Comment: The `actionPerformed` method is used when a button is clicked normally. If you want to do some fancy interaction with the button you can also use [other events](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/) like `mousePressed` in the MouseListener.

Comment: @Suresh I know you've been using GUI Builder. What you need to do is right-click the button from the design view and select `Events -> Action -> actionPerformed` then you will see auto-generated code in the source code.. Alex +1

Answer (score 10):

First, use a button, assign an ActionListener to it, in which you use JOptionPane to show the message.

```
class MyWindow extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final JTextBox textBox = new JTextBox("some text here");
        JButton button = new JButton("Click!");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, textBox.getText());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `JTextBox` is a real class. This doesn't work…

Answer (score 8):

You can also use lambda-function:

```
JButton button = new JButton("click me");
button.addActionListener(e ->
{
    // your code here
});
```

However, if you mean signals and slots like in Qt, then Swing does not support this. But you can always implement this yourself using the "Observer" pattern ([link](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer)).

Answer (score 0):

```
JButton jEightButton=new JButton();
    

jEightButton.addActionListener(this);

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    jframe.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.blue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public GUI() {

JButton btn1 = new JButton("Click me!");

add(btn1);

btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()) {

```
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            //action for the button
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).